# SPOJ PALIN programe running successfully on ideone,but showing wrong answer when i am posting it on SPOJ

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.

Input

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases. Integers K are given in the next t lines.

Output

For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K.

Example

Input:
2
808
2133

Output:
818
2222

My code which is working successfully on ideone but spoj shows "Wrong ans" ,can any one suggest me or correct me where i am wrong, here is my code;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int ifPalindrome(int n){
     int r=0,k=0,a=n;
     while((a%10)!=0){
     r=a%10;
     k=10*k+r;
     a=a/10;
     }
  if(k==n)return 1;
return 0;   
}
int main(){
    int t,n;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(;t>0;t--){
       scanf("%d",&n);
       while(ifPalindrome(n)!=1){
        n++;
       }    
      if(ifPalindrome(n)==1)printf("%d\n",n);   
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: An int can only hold numbers up to around 2 billion (10 digits), but you may have a 1 million digit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake that you are making is that you are storing `n` in an `integer datatype`... the constraint says that

> K of not more than 1000000 **digits** (it is `digits` and not up to that `number`)

It is impossible for an `integer` to store such a `huge number`..so you have to use `string` or `character array` or `integer array` to solve this particular problem... try this input:

> 454646546546546546546546464646464646

and you will realize where you are wrong